# Is this a new pentagonal tiling?

Tags: tiling

[image: Pentagonal Tiling]

I discovered this while thinking about the pentagonal tiling of type 15.  Is this a new type of tiling?  If it is, then I think I have found several other new pentagonal tilings like this one and the pentagonal tiling of type 15.  They all have vertices which lie in the field $ \mathbb{Q} (24) $.  The internal angles for a pentagon in the image above are

$ 60,150,90,120,120 $

And the lengths of the edges of a pentagon in the image above are

$1, \sqrt{3} ,1,1,2 $

Comment: Dang, that actually seems to tessellate. But I feel like there's a "mini-hexagon" in the top right that tessellates by itself...

Comment: This seems to be just a combination of two tilings. If those two are known, does this count as something new?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, there are fifteen types of convex pentagons known to tile the plane monohedrally: 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling

This tiling is related to type 15.

Comment: I added a new picture which shows how it is a combination of two tilings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About 6 or 7 years ago I did a computer search for various monohedral polygon tilings. I was hoping to find a 15th pentagon type, but got side-tracked into cataloguing all the tilings I found along the way. See [my tilings page](https://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/).

I did not find this one of yours, as it is 4-isohedral and I did not search for those much because my programs were too slow for that. The tile itself however is obviously of a known type, namely type 1 (two adjacent corners sum to 180, or equivalently two parallel sides). It is also of type 2. I would however be interested in seeing any other tilings you have found.

Recently Michaël Rao has announced a proof that the 15 known convex pentagon tile types are the only ones. You can read about it in [this article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/pentagon-tiling-proof-solves-century-old-math-problem-20170711/), and read the draft paper [here](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/michael.rao/publi.php?lang=en). It is plausible, but as it depends on an exhaustive computer search, it will be a while before it is replicated and confirmed.

Here is a picture of the tiling with the tiles coloured by isohedrality class:

[image]

During my searches I had also found a tiling using the exact same tile, but this one is 3-isohedral:

[image]